# YCbCr to RGB conversion MATLAB using ycbr2rgb results in pink picture

Tags: matlab, rgb

I'm trying to convert an YCbCr image to RGB ysing MATLAB's function ycbcr2rgb. My resulting picture ends up being pink, and converting back again afterwards (should give me the original picture?) creates yet another image mostly grey.

For reference I tried to convert each channel individually by formula and it ends up the same.

I'm using a bigtiff format because of large filesize and if any help the imfinfo shows compression using JPEG.

Here is my code:

```
x=imread('picture.tiff','Index',9); %(9 subresolutions)
rgb=ycbcr2rgb(x);
imshow(rgb);
```

Can it be because of MATLABs function using the originial definition of YCbCr using ranges from 16-235 while my image is ranging from 0-255? If so is there any means of correcting this using the inbuild function?

I have added the pictures [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz52m.jpg), first image is showing imshow(rgb), while the second image is the original ycbcr. What I noticed is that in the Windows image viewer it actually shows it correct, it's just MATLAB's imshow that displays it pink after conversion.

Is there any chance you could point me in the right direction?
Thanks
Sonny

Comment: Please post your (relevant) code

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm sure someone will be able to help, but please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn the best way to make that happen.

Comment: Thanks both of you.

To Bono: my code is more or less just
x=imread('picture.tiff','Index',9);
rgb=ycbcr2rgb(x);
imshow(rgb);

Comment: Maybe you could attach, post the picture.tiff somewhere/here/elswhere. Have you checked that Matlab can read the file properly? Maybe you can then give an example of function ycbr2rgb that fails without relying on an image but just by giving some artificial data and showing that it fails.

Comment: Hi Trilarion, thanks! I have added the pictures. The reason I didn't before is they are 4GB each, so i just took a snippet of it with a smaller resolution. Anyway I noticed as described in my edit that the Windows image viewer displays both the same, but MATLAB's imshow displays the rgb image as pink after conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently imread reads YCbCr images as RGB when loading it, which is why the problem occured.

Thanks for the help to all of you.

[imread documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014b/matlab/ref/imread.html)

Answer (score 0):

This link gives all the conversion formulae:
http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=11

Answer (score 0):

The below code converts image from RGB space to YCbCr space and back.

```
rgb = imread('board.tif');
imshow(rgb);
figure;
ycbcr = rgb2ycbcr(rgb);
imshow(ycbcr);
figure;
rgb2 = ycbcr2rgb(ycbcr);
imshow(rgb2);
```

Use MATLABs built in functions only. Also, if you're facing issues while converting from ycbcr to rgb you should probably try to convert the image to other form and then convert that form to RGB. (a dirty hack)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the build in functions doesn't seem to do the trick for me. The thing is that i'm using a bigtiff format since my filesizes are quite large, this makes me unable to convert to other ordinary formats.

Answer (score 0):

Just divide the image by 256 before converting it back to RGB.

```
y = ycbcr2rgb(z/256); % z holds the YCbCr image.
```

Worked for me.
Hope that helps :)